# Dark Mode Toggle in Tailwind CSS not working in older browsers

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, postcss, tailwind-3

I'm currently working on a project using Tailwind CSS for styling, and I've implemented a dark mode toggle feature. The toggle **works perfectly in the latest version of Chrome** but it **doesn't work in older versions** (e.g., Chrome 87 on Android).

When toggling to dark mode, the expected behavior is to apply dark mode classes like dark:bg-slate-900, but in older browsers, it keeps the light mode classes (e.g. bg-gray-50).

```
// tailwind.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
  },
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
}
```

```
// Dark mode toggle logic
useEffect(() => {
  if (
    localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark" ||
    localStorage.getItem("theme") === null
  ) {
    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#0f172a";
    document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
  } else {
    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor = "#fcfefc";
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
  }
}, [theme]);
```

```
// postcss.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
package.json file
{
  "name": "decker",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "vite": "5.0.12",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.17.4"
  }
}
```

How do I make dark and light mode work in older browsers as well?

Comment: What version of Tailwind are you running?

Comment: I am using Tailwind version 3.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tailwind v3.3+, the selectors of CSS rules for `dark:` variant classes with `darkMode: 'class'` [are generated with the `:is()` pseudo class](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/10766). [Can I use… reports this was supported in Chrome for Android starting from version 121](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo) and [MDN reports Chrome for Android support starting from version 88](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#browser_compatibility). Either way, this `:is()` usage would be why `dark:` variant classes have no effect on Chrome for Android version 87.

To work around this compatibility you could consider:

- Downgrading Tailwind to v3.2. Though do be aware of any v3.3 features you may be using will stop working.
- Have some PostCSS plugin that runs after Tailwind that converts `:is()` usage to some other CSS that is compatible, such as by using `:match()` or `:-webkit-any()`.
- Use a [custom variant via a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-variants) that emulates `darkMode: 'class'` CSS selectors in Tailwind versions older than v3.3 or that use `:match()` or `-webkit-any()`:

  ```js
  const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

  module.exports = {
    // …
    plugins: [
      plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
        // Tailwind v3.2 dark behavior.
        addVariant('daak', '.dark &');
        // OR
        // Using `:match()`.
        addVariant('daak', [':match(.dark &)', ':is(.dark &)']);
        // OR
        // Using `:-webkit-any()`.
        addVariant('daak', [':-webkit-any(.dark &)', ':is(.dark &)']);
      })
    ]
  }
  ```

  Though do be aware you'd need to replace all instances of `dark:` variant with the name of the custom variant declared in the Tailwind plugin (`daak:` in the above example).

Comment: After downgrading the Tailwind version to 3.2.7, toggling between dark and light themes worked on Chrome 87 (Android). I didn't face any issues because I wasn't using any new features or classes. Thanks.